# Is it possible to share video to facebook twitter using socialauth api in android?

Tags: android, video, file-sharing, socialauth

I am working on an application which uses socialauth api to integrate facebook and twitter authorization. But I want to know if it is possible to use the api to share or upload videos . I googled it but found nothing for videos sharing . Please suggest is it possible if yes how?

Comment: did you manage to get it to work?